# Use inheritance in MSTest for shared tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dynamics-crm, mstest

I'm trying to write Unittests for D365 Plugins and CodeActivities (both being classes). There are small tests that should run in every plugin, such as:

```
[TestMethod]
public void NullLocalPluginContext()
{
    XrmFakedContext context = new XrmFakedContext();

    Assert.ThrowsException<InvalidPluginExecutionException>(
        () => context.ExecutePluginWith<SomePlugin>(null));
}
```

Where `SomePlugin` is the class to be tested (which is for each child different) and cannot be abstract (awaits `IPlugin`). For example here it's a `CheckDuplicateOrder` in the child:

```
[TestClass]
public class CheckDuplicateOrderTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void NullLocalPluginContext()
    {
        XrmFakedContext context = new XrmFakedContext();

        Assert.ThrowsException<Exception>(
            () => context.ExecutePluginWith<CheckDuplicateOrder>(null));
    }
}
```

For these small tests I'd like to have this parent with Shared tests but I don't know how to reference the 'to-be' child's target.
I prefer MSTest, but any NuGet framework is accepted.

[Maybe this helps with understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYriG.png)

Every plugin would have it's own test class.
Every plugintest class needs the basic.
These basic tests should be inherited from parent (so they don't take up space).

Plugins: Dog, Cat, Mouse
PluginTests: DogTest, CatTest, MouseTest
BasePluginTest -> should have shared tests where `SomePlugin` in the exmaple is Dog/Cat/Mouse. But I don't know how to reference it. Every plugin would have a function `TestWalk() { .. ExecutePluginWith<SomePlugin>}`. The Cat should call CatTest, the Dog should call DogTest.

Comment: I don´t get your question. Can you elaborate on how `Context`, `SomePlugin` and `CheckDuplicateOrder` relate to one another? The image isn´t helpful at all, as it contains completely different classes.

Comment: @Houkouha You sholdn't use class inheritance in unit tests. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44861/unit-testing-test-class-inheritance-vs-single-test-class

Comment: @HimBromBeere Sure, info after image link. Context is just a fake environment with filled entities, doesn't matter here. I'm trying to write something like 'child.target.class' insted of 'someplugin', but it doesn't accept IPlugin abstract.

Comment: @PWND do I just hide it under a region and copy paster after each new created class?

Comment: @Houkouha, as you wish. The main idea - the unit test, it's a 'unit' and should be independent.

Comment: Each test should be valuable enough to have its own implementation...

Comment: if you feel there´s some common behaviour between your test-classes you may introduce some class for the common functionality and use that class within your tests - as if your test-class was a normal class. In fact those are pretty similar to normal classes and thus you have the same rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: some people won't like this because it abuses class inheritance to save code.  It's a potential tool for the job, you can evaluate whether it works for you or not.

This seems like it could be achievable with a base class to define the shared tests.  Maybe something like this would achieve what you're trying to do?

```
// note: no [TestClass] on this type so it doesn't get discovered by MSTest.  
// Probably should also be abstract.
public class SharedTests<T> where T : IPlugin
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void NullLocalPluginContext()
    {
        XrmFakedContext context = new XrmFakedContext();

        Assert.ThrowsException<Exception>(
            () => context.ExecutePluginWith<T>(null));
    }
}
```

Your plugin classes would inherit from this class:

```
[TestClass]
public class CheckDuplicateOrderTests : SharedTests<CheckDuplicateOrder>
{
    // NullLocalPluginContext test is inherited from the parent type
}

[TestClass]
public class SomeOtherPluginTests : SharedTests<SomeOtherPlugin>
{
    // Also has NullLocalPluginContext test inherited, but for testing SomeOtherPlugin
}
```

Comment: Maybe that is to be considered as `abuse`, not sure about that. However I am not found of this from a maintainability perspective.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not a big fan of this approach either, but nor am I a fan of duplicating code N times (for values of N > 3).  On my team, we do a little of both in our tests, and some factors we consider are the amount of code being duplicated, the number of times it's going to be duplicated, and how often we see changes in the design of the code affected (really, all of which are indicators of how much it might cost to maintain N copies in the future).  All of those considerations lead to a subjective conclusion though...

Comment: Agree, pragmatic for the win. I would also have readability as a factor, and if all you find is zero code and a comment... the novel reader will most likely be confused!

Answer (score 1):

As with a normal class you should favour composition over inheritance. Even
though test-classes do not *have* to follow the same rules and guidelines as normal classes doesn't mean we cannot implement them.

So when you feel you have some common functionality accross your test-classes you should extract some class that is used by your tests. You would do the same for a normal business-class also, won´t you?

```
class CommonFunc 
{ 
    public static bool NullLocalPluginContext<T, TException>() where T: IPlugIn, TException : Exception
    {
        XrmFakedContext context = new XrmFakedContext();
        try { context.ExecutePluginWith<T>(null)) };
        catch (T e) { return true; }
        return false;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class CheckDuplicateOrderTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void NullLocalPluginContext()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(CommonFunc.NullLocalPluginContext<CheckDuplicateOrder, Exception>(null));
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class SomeOtherPluginTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void NullLocalPluginContext()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(CommonFunc.NullLocalPluginContext<SomePlugin, InvalidPluginExecutionException>(null));
    }
}
```

You could also make your common method rethrow the exception instead of just returning `true` or `false` if you want to log the actual exception being thrown within the test-framework.